# custom datalabels in excel charts with C# using Microsoft Office Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, charts, interop

I created a chart in Excel with C# using Microsoft Office Interop Excel and I am having trouble to customize the datalabels

```
SeriesCollection seriesCollection7 = myChart7.Chart.SeriesCollection();
Series series7 = seriesCollection7.NewSeries();
series7.XValues = xValues7;
series7.Values = values7;
Excel.DataLabel dl1 = (Excel.DataLabel)series7.DataLabels(); // ERROR HERE
dl1.NumberFormat = "#0.0%";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPTION 1 (thanks @Jack-J-Jun-MSFT )

```
        chartPage7.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, true, true);
        series7.HasDataLabels = true;
        Excel.DataLabel dl1 = series7.DataLabels(0);
        dl1.NumberFormat = "#,0%";
```

OPTION 2

```
        chartPage7.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, true, true); // set label

        series7.DataLabels().NumberFormat = "#,0%";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to customize the datalabels.

```
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("D:\\3.XLSX");
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)worksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = worksheet.ChartObjects(1);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
        Excel.Series series1 = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(1);
        series1.HasDataLabels = true;
        Excel.DataLabel dl1 = series1.DataLabels(1);
        dl1.Text = "Test1";
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
```

I make a column chart and I set the first point of the first Datalabel.

Like the following:

[image]

Comment: I will try your option. But i had trouble to have SeriesCollection accepting a 1 or something as a parameter between ().

Comment: What i found as a solution was like this.     

       // This will add datalabels
            chartPage7.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, true, true); // set label

            // This will change dalabels format
            series7.DataLabels().NumberFormat = "#,0%";

Comment: @EstebanSantos, what error you get when you use SeriesCollection(1);? If you have found the solution, please make an answer and mark it.

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution in an isolated example and it worked perfect. And i finally understand the way to handle the reference number in brackets. <br/>             chartPage7.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, true, true); 
            series7.HasDataLabels = true;
            Excel.DataLabel dl1 = series7.DataLabels(0);
            dl1.NumberFormat = "#,0%"; <br/>    <br/>    My first option with a twist also worked.              series7.DataLabels().NumberFormat = "#,0%" Thanks